# Refresh a select tag to default value

Tags: javascript, html

I have 2 select tag. I want to refresh the values in the 2nd select tag to default , when the user click on the first select tag. How do I achieve it in Javascript

Comment: What you have tried first?

Comment: you can use `change` event of first select and update the another select in that event

Comment: By `to default` you mean remove any values that was added dynamically or change selected value back to it's origin value?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use [`onchange`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp) event to perform this task. The idea is when the first select is changed, you set the default value (here I choose to set to the first item of the list, but you can do whatever you need to re-initialize its value).

```js
function initialize() {
  var select_car = document.getElementById("select_car");
  var select_power = document.getElementById("select_power");
  
  select_car.selectedIndex = 0;
  select_power.selectedIndex = 0;
  
  select_car.addEventListener("change", function() {
    select_power.selectedIndex = 1;  
  });
}
```

```html
<body onload="initialize()">
<select id="select_car">
  <option disabled>-- Select a car --</option>
  <option>Mazda MX5</option>
  <option>Nissan Skyline GTR</option>
</select>
<select id="select_power">
  <option disabled>-- Select a power --</option>
  <option>150CV</option>
  <option>255CV</option>
</select>
</body>
```